# Can set hostname of VPS buy from https://bandwagonhost.com

Tags: hostname, vps, wordpress

I buy a VPS server from bandwagon , here is this server 's info

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6bCu.png)

then I install a wordpress blog in this server , now I can visit my blog by type :
http://myIP

but I can not visit my blog by : http://TeckAndOtherNotesOfLY2018.com

can anyone tell me what I still need to do to make hostname valid ?

Comment: You need to register the domainname TeckAndOtherNotesOfLy2018.com and get the A record pointing to "myip"

Comment: I’m sorry if this sounds rude, but please stop right there. Before running your own server and hosting a widely-used (and thus frequently-attacked) application like Wordpress on it, please learn about server administration and whatnot in a protected environment first. If you can’t or won’t do that, go for regular web hosting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "hostname" parameter in VPS control panels only changes what the server calls *itself* (i.e. reverse DNS), but it doesn't change how the rest of the world sees the server nor the domain.

(In other words, you're changing "server → domain" but you need "domain → server".)

According to WHOIS, the domain `teckandothernotesofly2018.com` currently doesn't exist; it's not owned by anybody. For it to exist, you first need to **register and purchase** it from one of the many dozen domain registrar companies.

Most registrars will automatically provide free DNS hosting, and a web-based DNS control panel. Use that to point the domain *to* the server's IP address.